# How to get the windows username from external server?

Tags: c#, .net, angular

I'm working with angular2 application with .net for that I need to get windows username. I'm getting correct username  only on local host by using following code.

```
string username= .Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`
```

If i use the same code from external server means i'm getting `APPPOOL\xyz`.

How to get the windows username from external server?

There is no login form. It should use windows authentication.

Comment: Im guessing your app is web based? Are you using ntlm authentication?

Comment: @BugFinder yes it is web application only and im not using ntlm authentication.

Comment: If you were it would pick it up :D

Comment: If you're using IIS then turn on the Windows Authentication mode on the server OS and on the IIS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/

Comment: @MarcusHöglund Yup I tried by enabling windows authentication and disabled anonymous authentication

Answer (score 0):

Use WTSEnumerateSessions to get a list of sessions on the specified terminal service server, then use WTSQuerySessionInformation  to get the user names.

You can find .Net wrappers of these functions at http://code.google.com/p/cassia/

Comment: Is there any other way??. Its seems like have to add dll in my application. Have to do without adding dll.

Comment: @Vijay Cassia DLL is most popular solution i think

Comment: tried with Cassia DLL. Its working fine while using **http://localhost:20327/api** but not in **http://c2dev38/irozwebapi/api** its returing 401 (Unauthorized) error. Bot both are having same code. Kindly do help

Comment: @Vijay Did you make corresponding changes in server OS?